# Cloud 9 Node js. Can't connect to process.env.Port anymore. EADDRINUSE Error

Tags: node.js

Have tried do work out this simple code in cloud9 
but it seems like some process is already located 
on process.env.PORT and I can't seem to find it.
Have tried killing nodes searching for nodes.

And i'm not entirely sure how to connect to port like 3000 on cloud9. (localhost:3000)

```
Debugger listening on port 15454
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
    at listen (net.js:1270:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/script.js:5:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
```

The code

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(process.env.PORT);
```